# How to pass live data to Widgets inside another class with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So, I'm still fairly new to flutter and I don't quite understand how to get the data to flow logically.

I have this as the very top of my sign up pages logic:

```
class _SignUpPageTextFieldsAndLabels extends State<SignUpPageTextFieldsAndLabels>{
  _SignUpPageTextFieldsAndLabels();

  final _emailField = EntryPageTextFormField('Email', Icons.clear);
  final _firstNameField = EntryPageTextFormField('First Name', Icons.clear);
  final _surnameField = EntryPageTextFormField('Surname', Icons.clear);
  final _cellNumberField = EntryPageTextFormField('Cellphone Number', Icons.clear);
  final _passwordField = EntryPagePasswordTextFormField('Password');
  final _passwordConfirmField = EntryPagePasswordTextFormField('Confirm Password');
  final _photoUploadField = _SignUpPageUploadPhotoButton();
  final _faithDropDown = _DecoratedDropdownForFaithSelection();

  List _GetFieldData() {
    List userSignUpData = List.filled(SIGN_UP_PAGE_NUM_DATA_FIELDS, '');
    
    userSignUpData[PASSWORD] = _passwordField.GetText();
    userSignUpData[EMAIL] = _emailField.GetText();
    userSignUpData[DISPLAY_NAME] = _firstNameField.GetText();
    userSignUpData[SURNAME] = _surnameField.GetText();
    userSignUpData[CELL_NUMBER] = _cellNumberField;
    userSignUpData[FAITH] = _faithDropDown.GetDropdownValue();
    userSignUpData[IMAGE] = _photoUploadField.photoURL;
    
    return userSignUpData;
  }

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(30, 0, 30, 0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          const CustomBackButton(),
          const ThePatriotLogo(),
          const _SignUpLabelArea(),
          _firstNameField,
          _surnameField,
          _cellNumberField,
          _emailField,
          _passwordField,
          _passwordConfirmField,
          _photoUploadField,
          _faithDropDown,
          _SignUpCreateAccountIconButton(_GetFieldData),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Obviously, each field has a separate class (for code cleanliness) that handles the way those Widgets are structured and also logic. The actual account creation occurs inside _SignUpCreateAccountIconButton().

Now, my problem is that the data that is passed to the account creation is all empty. I assume that this is caused by the fields not actively passing data to account creation. It only sends the data once, at Widget construction. But I'm kinda stumped as to how I can send data when the Button inside _SignUpCreateAccountIconButton() is clicked? Or am I going about this totally wrong?

Comment: I would 1st start with a proper state management. Bloc is one of them. There you also find an example on authorization: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't store your widgets in private fields of the parent widget. This breaks the rebuild-cycle and comes with a bunch of problems. The same goes for helper methods. Instead, instantiate the widgets in your parent directly.

This means, instead of:

```
...
final _emailField = EntryPageTextFormField('Email', Icons.clear);
...
[
const _SignUpLabelArea(),
_firstNameField,
]
```

do

```
[
const _SignUpLabelArea(),
EntryPageTextFormField('Email', Icons.clear),
]
```

As for the data-flow. If you have your parent widget as a `StatefulWidget`, you use the `setState(...)` method to indicate a data-change and to signalize Flutter to rebuild the UI with the new data. This would look something like this:

```
void myValueChanges(String incomingValue) {
  setState(() {
    _instanceValue = incomingValue;
  });
}
```

What you see there is a callback method you can pass to the `onChange`-handler of `TextField`s for example. It updates a cached copy of the value and rebuilds the UI starting from the widget `setState` was invoked in. You can read more about `setState` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html).

Finally, to pass data down to children and have them rebuild accordingly, there are several solutions, a few of them would be:

1. Pass the data and a callback function that invokes setState(..) directly to the child widget.
2. Use a state management solution like Bloc or Provider
3. Create your own custom solution (I would not recommend that).

Comment: How does one pass or access the data without having the Widget as a named private Field? I originally had all of the Widgets directly instantiated but then I didn't know how to then call the GetText from a FormField. How does one actually access data from directly instantiated widgets?

Comment: The child widget will receive a callback like myValueChanges(...) in the example above. This callback is defined in the parent and called by the child, so the parent gets notified if the value changes.

Comment: Yeah, that just made it all click in my head. Thanks for the time you gave to explain it to me.